# Create a folder structure using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to create this folder structure using PowerShell:

```
D:\feb\win10\x64\Folder1
                 folder2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `New-Item` cmdlet.

Here an example to create a single folder using the `New-Item` cmdlet:

```
New-item "D:\feb#16\LV2\7212\win10\x64\audio" -ItemType Directory -force
```

---

Certainly you could do this for each the subfolders you want to create. You could also create a list of your subfolders using `@('folder1' ,'folder2', ...)` and iterate over these subfolders to create them. The following example uses the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine the base path with the current sub folder which is `$_` (the current pipeline object) and creates the directory using the above mentioned `New-Item` cmdlet:

```
@('audio', 'chipset', 'communication', 'docks', 'input', 'network', 'security', 'storage', 'video') |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Item (Join-Path 'D:\feb#16\LV2\7212\win10\x64\' $_) -ItemType Directory -force
    }
```

---

Comment: I feel that this might be over-complicated for a newbie. I would recommend you include a most basic example to create a single folder and explain your code in a bit more detail!

Comment: as a newbie its helped me your descriptions also to understand.
am expecting more helps from you guys. :)

Comment: hi @MartinBrandl can you help me the same scenario with parsing a Excel sheet for giving folder names. like Audio,chip set.....

Comment: probably yes, but please start a new question

Comment: @MartinBrandl ok i will start a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323377/i-would-like-to-create-this-folder-structure-using-parsing-a-excel-sheet-in-powe